# Parse HTML using DOM or other in ASP.NET without installing anything on webserver

Tags: c#, asp.net, dom, html-parsing

How do I parse HTML on an external page and read its contents (eg. get the contents inside a DIV-element from google.com).

Setup:

```
var wc = new WebClient();
wc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("<username>", "<password>");
String strHtml = wc.DownloadString("http://google.com");
```

The webserver have .NET framework 4.5.

Fetching the content as a string (strHtml) is not a necessity.

Preferrably reading the DOM without the prerequisite to installing any .DLL, rendering **Html Agility Pack** not an option. Regular Expression is also not an option, I need a more solid way.

The search target should be able to be described in a string-like fashion as it should be possible to pass it as an argument to the .aspx using the URL address-bar.

I have found a lot of information on using the DOM API in PHP, but what is the ASP.NET equivalent?

Comment: `Html Agility Pack` is good option

Comment: I can't install the Html Agility Pack on the server in question.